# Отключить автоматический выбор первого метода доставки в WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

По умолчанию, в WooCommerce при оформлении заказа, автоматически выбирается самый первый способ доставки. Подскажите, как отключить этот выбор?

Нужно, чтобы клиент самостоятельно выбирал вариант доставки. А то бывают случаи, когда клиент просто забывает об этом или спешит, и оплачивает не ту доставку.

Решения найти не смог. Буду рад вашей помощи!

Answer (score 0):

Подобный вопрос задавался на ENG ресурсе (6К просмотров, 5 лет назад).
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377151/how-to-disable-default-shipping-and-payment-options-on-checkout-with-woocommerce]

Последнее, что добавлено:

> This does only remove the default selection. If the selection is stored in your session it will be applied as normal. Keep that in mind when testing.

> Edit: Unfortunately, since WooCommerce 4+ this does not work anymore.

То есть с 4 той версии способ не работает

Кроме того, в одном из ответов есть:

> Hm, I'm not sure what the best way to do that is now when the filter is removed. Maybe you can just reset the chosen methods in the users session like this in an appropriate place in your code(you only want to run this once before the checkout is loaded the first time as it will reset the selection after the customer have made otherwise):
> WC()->session->set( 'chosen_payment_method', '' );
> and WC()->session->set( 'chosen_shipping_methods', '' );

То есть обнулять выбор... Но тут надо тестить.

У меня такие траблы, но у меня менеджеры связываются.

От себя добавлю. Как вариант, сделать вариант по умолчанию -"не доставлять" и проверять при оформлении. Если "Не доставлять", то выводить оповещение и не давать переходить к следующему этапу!

Ну и напоследок - посмотри плагины.